# Eclipse not exporting full .apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

So I updated my Android Application lately and exported it to a .apk so I could send it to some other android phones. The exportation finished without errors, and everything was fine. But when I installed the app using the .apk, it seemed like I got an older- or half version of the app. Some functions don't work at all, and the app takes about 50% less space on the other phones. On my own phone, the app works perfectly and takes all the space it's supposed to. The weird thing is that I'm using the same .apk to install the app on both my own phone and the other phones.

Is there a possible error or solution for this? I really need the new functions, or the app won't work well! I also searched for a solution for hours, so don't blame me if there's already a same question out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean

Select your project in Package Explorer

Go to Project in menu and select clean.

Press F5

If this does not works

Try restarting eclipse else restart your PC

> Sometimes Eclipse will not be able to access your files if they are not referenced correctly.

If this does not works try putting your code here that is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Well I tried to clean up too many times, hell, I even created a new Android project and copied all files over to see if it made a difference. I've been searching a lot, and I found out the problem might be the keystore. Once I renamed the project folder, and had to create a new keystore, maybe this is causing the project to be some versions older? I don't know, but I really, really need this to work, so if you have any answers, I'm glad to hear them!